# Permutations of Dataset

Tags: dataset, associations, permutation

I have data with missing values. I need all permutations which follow the two rules: Every year must be represented in each draw; and each draw must contain  a minimum of two elements for each year. Here is the data.

```
assoc = <|
   "A" -> <|"1990" -> "Aretn1", "1991" -> "Aretn2", 
     "1992" -> "Aretn3", "1993" -> "Aretn4", "1994" -> "Aretn5"|>, 
   "B" -> <|"1990" -> "Bretn1", "1991" -> "Bretn2", 
     "1992" -> "Bretn3", "1993" -> "Bretn4", "1994" -> "Bretn5"|>, 
   "C" -> <|"1990" -> "", "1991" -> "", "1992" -> "", 
     "1993" -> "Cretn4", "1994" -> "Cretn5"|>, 
   "D" -> <|"1990" -> "Dretn1", "1991" -> "Dretn2", 
     "1992" -> "Dretn3", "1993" -> "", "1994" -> ""|>, 
   "E" -> <|"1990" -> "", "1991" -> "", "1992" -> "", 
     "1993" -> "Eretn4", "1994" -> "Eretn5"|>|>;
```

Using the brute strength method, here are the permutations that qualify

[image]

Clearly a picking function using an elaborate Module with Reap and Sow or Select would do it. But I am trying to use more code efficient methods of Query or Counts that Datasets and Associations were created for

Comment: You might not be able to do much better than `Subsets` followed by `Select` with an appropriate filter criterion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not scale well.

### Step 1: Normalize the data.

It's usually best to let absense represent itself rather than use special tokens.

```
normAssoc = DeleteCases[""] /@ assoc
```

### Step 2: Reverse the mapping

Let's look at the data in terms of years, since we eventually want to use *year coverage* as a criterion.

```
byYear = Merge[KeyValueMap[Thread@*Reverse@*Rule, Keys /@ normAssoc], Identity]
```

This gives

```
<|"1990" -> {"A", "B", "D"}, "1991" -> {"A", "B", "D"}, "1992" -> {"A", "B", "D"}, "1993" -> {"A", "B", "C", "E"}, "1994" -> {"A", "B", "C", "E"}|>
```

### Step 3: Create yearly options

We want each year represented twice. So, we can create all 2-element subsets for each year's "coverage group".

```
byYear2Choices = Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ byYear
```

This gives

```
<|"1990" -> {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "D"}, {"B", "D"}}, 
  "1991" -> {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "D"}, {"B", "D"}}, 
  "1992" -> {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "D"}, {"B", "D"}}, 
  "1993" -> {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "C"}, {"A", "E"}, {"B", "C"}, {"B", "E"}, {"C", "E"}}, 
  "1994" -> {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "C"}, {"A", "E"}, {"B", "C"}, {"B", "E"}, {"C", "E"}}|>
```

Depending on what you want, we might want to instead create subsets of at least size 2.

### Step 4: Make a choice for each year

Now just select one of the choices that covers each year. There will be a lot of overlap, so we'll use Union to eliminate duplicates.

```
result = Union[Union@*Flatten /@ Tuples[Values[byYear2Choices]]]
```

This gives

```
{{"A", "B"}, 
 {"A", "B", "C"}, 
 {"A", "B", "D"}, 
 {"A", "B", "E"}, 
 {"A", "C", "D"}, 
 {"A", "D", "E"}, 
 {"B", "C", "D"}, 
 {"B", "D", "E"}, 
 {"A", "B", "C", "D"},
 {"A", "B", "C", "E"}, 
 {"A", "B", "D", "E"}, 
 {"A", "C", "D", "E"}, 
 {"B", "C", "D", "E"}, 
 {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}}
```